# ATL headers missing when using the VC++ 2015 toolchain on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atl

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for a C++ project (created with VS 2015). I get the following error:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(345): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atltrace.h': No such file or directory

How can I install the ATL/MFC headers of the VS 2015 toolchain?

## Details

- "Platform Toolset" setting (at "Project properties/General/Platform Toolset")

  - set to "Visual Studio 2015 (v140),
  - changing the platform toolset to "Visual Studio 2017 (v141) compiles fine.
- Files on disc

  - The include directory for VS 2015 (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\`) contains `afx*.h` files but *no* `atl*.h` files.
  - These missing files seem to belong to `VC_ATL.Headers.msi` ("Visual C++ Library ATL Headers Package") (which I checked on another machine with those files). I could not get the respective msi to install. (I took the msi from the other machine.) Error: "To install this product, please run Setup.exe. [...]".
  - The respective directory for VS 2017 (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include\`) *does contain* those files.
- Installer

  - "Windows Desktop Development with C++/VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset for desktop (x86,x64)" is checked.
  - It seems to me that the v140 toolset is missing the ATL/MFC headers.
  - "Windows Desktop Development with C++/MFC and ATL support(x86 and x64)" does not seem relevant, it seems to be about the VS 2017 version.
- VC++ redistributable seems irrelevant since those do not contain the header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/announcing-the-official-release-of-the-visual-c-build-tools-2015/) about the Visual C++ Build Tools 2015. The build tools are also released in a standalone version without the need to install Visual Studio 2015:

> The Build Tools are the same C++ tools that you get with Visual Studio 2015 but they come in a scriptable standalone installer that only lays down the tools you need to build C++ projects.

Microsoft has included ATL/MFC.

They can be downloaded from http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools - ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190111183958/https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe)). Make sure to select "ATL and MFC" which is deselected by default.

Comment: When I upgraded my project to use v140 toolset, after closing and reopening VS 2015, my project was not loaded.  When I tried to load it, VS told me I needed to install these tools and took me to the installer.  I had though that I had all of VS 2015 installed, but it looks like I did not.

Comment: I wish the links in this answer weren't broken so I could see if the answer worked.

Comment: @Andrew Have you tried finding the links and updating the post to the new links?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes. I have found and installed about 20 gb worth of things to try to fix this issue and absolutely nothing has worked.

Comment: A similar page might be https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/ although it doesn't seem to be exactly the same and the link labeled "2015 Tool" goes to 2019.